# Drawing rotated Rectangle

Tags: c++, graphics, 2d, computational-geometry

So I'm writting a function that takes a point and rotates it around another point at a certain angle, so when I draw a rectangle, I want that rectangle to be rotated as well,but it's distorted.I'm also drawing two colored rectangles, one without rotation and one rotated by the angle provided, like in this picture:

[image: picture]

The purple outline should look like the red one.
This is the code for the rotation

```
 double d2r(double d)
        {
            return (d / 180.0) * ((double)M_PI);
        }

 double sind(double x) 
        {

            return std::sin(d2r(x));
        }


 double cosd(double x) 
        {
            return std::cos(d2r(x));
        }


std::pair<double, double> rotate_around(double x, double y, double o_x, double o_y, double angle)
{


    x = o_x + (x - o_x) * cosd(angle) - (y - o_y) * sind(angle);
    y = o_y + (y - o_y) * cosd(angle) + (x - o_x) * sind(angle);

    return std::pair<double, double>(x, y);

}
```

The function rotate_around is called with the following parameters
(original x, original y , middle x of the rectangle, middle y of the rectangle, angle of the rectangle)

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: answering literally: you are not telling us what is wrong with the code. Dont you get the expected results? Did you check your formulas? Did you use a debugger to step through your code?

Comment: btw the fact that you have to explain the meaning of variables is a good indicator that you should have choosen better names. If first parameter is "original x" why not call it `original_x` ? Or use a `std::pair<double,double> original_point`

Comment: ...are you sure about the order or parameters? From just looking at the code I would rather guess that `o_x` and `o_y` are the original coordinates

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, it's my first time asking question, yes I checked the order of the parameters.

Comment: An issue: `y` calculation uses the new `x`coordinate, not the original one. The consequence of a confusing naming

Comment: Yes, that was the problem , using the new x coordinates, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
x-= o_x; y-= o_y;
angle= d2r(angle);
double c= std::cos(angle), s= std::sin(angle);

return std::pair<double, double>(o_x + x * c - y * s, o_y + y * c + x * s);
```

will work.